# Merging different number of rows with some common data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

I have a data like this in an excel sheet:

```
Rensi   06/10/2020      
Rensi   07/10/2020      
Rensi   08/10/2020      
Sam     06/10/2020      
Sam     08/10/2020      
Mathew  07/10/2020
```

I want to make it like this in excel:

```
Rensi   06/10/2020  07/10/2020  08/10/2020
Sam     06/10/2020              08/10/2020
Mathew              07/10/2020
```

Comment: Just use a Pivot table. If dates are MDY, Name--Rows, Months-->Columns, Date-->Values (and select Max of Dates). If Dates are DMY, then instead Date-->Columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My method is using "Remove Duplicates" function and adding the auxiliary row to match date.

Step 1

Copying the column of Name to other column, then go to Data > Data Tools group > Remove Duplicates, then you would get a list of unique name.

Step 2

The same step of Step 1 to get the unique list the date. Then please copy these date > choose the correct cell > right-click > Transpose under Paste Options.

[image]

Step 3

Enter the formula below in Cell H2, then pull right and pull down.

`=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$6=$G2)*($B$1:$B$6=H$1),$B$1:$B$6)=0,"",SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$6=$G2)*($B$1:$B$6=H$1),$B$1:$B$6))`

Step 4

Choose the region from H2 to J4 > right click > Format Cells > select Date.

[image]